# JavaScript: у элемента удалить определенный класс из множества

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на JavaScript(без использования  Jquery и прочих библиотек) из множества установленных `<div>` элементу классов удалить определенный?

Чтобы функция работала в IE6, т.е. `classList.remove('');` не пойдёт.

Например:

```
<div id="id1"> 
   <div class="myclass1 item_checked">1</div>   
   <div class="myclass2 item_checked">2</div> 
   <div class="myclass3 nextclass3 item_checked">3</div> 
   <div class="myclass4 nextclass4 item_checked">4</div> 
   <div class="myclass5 nextclass5">5</div> 
</div>
```

Нужно у всех `<div>` блоков удалить только класс  `item_checked`, чтобы получилось:

```
<div id="id1"> 
   <div class="myclass1">1</div>   
   <div class="myclass2">2</div> 
   <div class="myclass3 nextclass3">3</div> 
   <div class="myclass4 nextclass4">4</div> 
   <div class="myclass5 nextclass5">5</div> 
</div>
```

Спасибо!

Comment: меняй className

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```js
function removeClass(obj, name) {
  var clsList = obj.className.split(" "); //Получаем массив классов
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < clsList.length; i++) {
    if (clsList[i] != name) //Проверяем наличие класса
      result.push(clsList[i]);
  }
  obj.className = result.join(" "); //Я не уверен, есть ли IE6 join. Если нет, придется делать цикл.
}

function removeClick() {
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    removeClass(divs[i], "item_checked");
  }
}
```

```css
.item_checked {
  color: red;
}
.fooitem_checkedbar {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <div class="myclass1 item_checked">1</div>
  <div class="myclass2 item_checked">2</div>
  <div class="myclass3 nextclass3 item_checked">3</div>
  <div class="myclass4 nextclass4 item_checked item_checked">4 - with two item_checked class</div>
  <div class="myclass5 nextclass5 fooitem_checkedbar">5 - with fooitem_checkedbar</div>
</div>
<button onclick="removeClick()">Remove item_checked</button>
```

Comment: join есть. Во времена ie6 он, даже, работал  быстрее чем конкатенация строк в цикле. Иногда встречал рекомендации оптимизировать таким образом построение длинной строки.

Comment: Извиняюсь за прошлый комментарий - не посмотрел что `indexOf` IE9+

Comment: @Arnial он и сейчас работает быстрее чем в цикле. Долгая конкатенация - плата за неизменяемость строк.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id1").getElementsByClassName("item_checked");
  var z = x.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    var y = x[0].className;
    k = /\bitem_checked\b/i;
    x[0].className = y.replace(k, '');
  }
  console.log(document.getElementById("id1").getElementsByTagName("div"))


}
```

```css
.item_checked {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <div class="myclass1 item_checked">1111111</div>
  <div class="myclass2 item_checked">222222</div>
  <div class="myclass3 nextclass3 item_checked">33333333</div>
  <div class="myclass4 nextclass4 item_checked">4444444</div>
  <div class="myclass5 nextclass5 foritem_checkedee item_checked">55555555</div>
  <div class="myclass5 nextclass5 item_checked foritem_checkedee ">66666666</div>
</div>

<button onclick="foo()">click me</button>
```

Comment: @Arnial исправил...

Comment: А если в классе `myclass5` будут стили и `item_checked`, и `foritem_checkedee`, то разве не заменится `foritem_checkedee` на `fordee`

Comment: @NewDevelop изменил условие, не заменилось..))

Comment: @C.Raf.T не заменилось благодоря Вашей выборки *div*ов. Потому что вы берете все *div* с классом `item_checked`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну так вроде условие было такое....

Comment: Условие было убрать класс `item_checked` у элемента. В Вашем примере, если заменить `document.getElementById("id1").getElementsByClassName("item_checked")` на `document.getElementById("id1").getElementsByTagName("div")`, то класс `foritem_checkedee` заменится на `fordee`.

Comment: К тому же, если у элемента присутствует класс `item_checked` больше одного раза, например `class="myclass3 item_checked item_checked "`, то у Вас уберется только одно совпадение, т.е. будет `class="myclass3 item_checked"`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko был конкретный вопрос, я дал на него решение. Если бы стоял вопрос, что может быть несколько одинаковых классов  у элемента ответ был бы другой. А если у вас встречаются в одном элементе два одинаковых класса, то это сугубо ваши трудности. у меня такого нет...

Comment: но если в 5-м классе foritem_checkedee будет идти перед item_checked, то оно как раз и заменится на fordee, а  item_checked останется. Можно попробовать использовать теги \b и \B для начала и конца слова.

Comment: Для особо предирчевых, изменил код....

Comment: @NewDevelop хороший пример, я не додумался. Как поведет себя Ваш алгоритм, если будет следующий набор классов у элемента `class="myclass3 foritem_checkedee item_checked"`?

Comment: @C.Raf.T не надо переходить на личности и обижаться. Мы же стараемся сделать Ваш код лучше! Что бы он работал в разных условиях. Надо уметь принимать конструктивную критику.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko не надо делать мой код лучше... Всегда можно найти более лучший вариант. Есть задача,  есть решение. Задача изменилась, соответственно решение тоже...

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); // загрузить в массив все доступные теги div

for (key in arr) { // выбирать каждый тег div из массива
  var s = arr[key].getAttribute('class'); // в s положить содержимое атрибута очередного тега div 

  if (s !== null) // если нет атрибута-class пропускаем
    if (s.lastIndexOf('item_checked') > 1) // если в s есть слово item_checked - значит это то что нам нужно 
      arr[key].setAttribute('class', s.substr(0, s.length - 13)); // установить атрибут class укороченной строкой s на 13 символов (это длина слова item_checked + пробел перед ним)

  console.log(arr[key]); // вывод в лог браузера для демонстрации
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <div class="myclass1 item_checked">1</div>
  <div class="myclass2 item_checked">2</div>
  <div class="myclass3 nextclass3 item_checked">3</div>
  <div class="myclass4 nextclass4 item_checked">4</div>
  <div class="myclass5 nextclass5">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваш код поведет себя неправильно если у элемента будет класс вроде `fooitem_checkedbar`

Comment: @PavelMayorov был конкретный вопрос , вроде не считается

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky добавил комментарии к коду